# How can I change accounts when I am trying to open up a restricted Google Form?

Tags: url, google-forms, google-account

My web browser is logged into multiple Google accounts and I have a restricted Google Form URL like this that I need to open with a specific account.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/XxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXx/viewform

Google Forms does not have a UI method to `switch accounts` like many of their other products and it will always try to open the form with the default account (the first one that you authenticated against in your web browser).

Is there a way to make it open in the right account?

Answer (score 94):

As it turns out there is, although this is not apparent anywhere on Google's help site from what I could find.

If you modify the URL and add `u/1/` immediately after `https://docs.google.com/forms/` then you will be logged into the form using the second Google account that you are authenticated against in your browser.

**Note:** You will be redirected during this process, so the final URL in your browser will look a little different, but you should be connected to the form with the right account.

https://docs.google.com/forms/u/1/d/e/XxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXx/viewform

You can change that number to match whichever account that you want to use.

- *Not sure how to determine the account number*?

  - Look at your Google Mail URL for the account you want. It will look something like this (and has the number you need in it): https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox

Also, remember that your Google accounts start counting from 0. So, your first account is 0, your second one is 1, etc.

Comment: Great trick! I often change the `/u/#` url to go directly to a specific Drive or Photos, but as this url didn't have the `/u` part I didn't think it was possible. It would have been too optimistic for me to try that, LOL.

Comment: Note that the `/viewform` at the end is important - if omitted, it may redirect to an editing URL and cause issues.

Answer (score 7):

The initial answer does work, but it is not as user friendly for those who are not comfortable with computers.

You can use the URL below to have the users pick their account and then be redirected afterwards:

```
https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/{formId}/viewform&service=wise
```

Comment: Thank you! This URL prefix is so useful.